# ASP.NET private font in pdf sharp not displaying properly

Tags: c#, asp.net, fonts, truetype, pdfsharp

The private font that I am trying to use in my pdf is not displaying as it should.  I have looked at the PDF sharp sample on their wiki, as well as examples online, but cannot get it to display with the custom font. Can anyone see anything wrong with the code below?

```
    PrivateFontCollection pfc = new PrivateFontCollection();

    pfc.AddFontFile(Server.MapPath(@"~\Content\Fonts\Exo-Regular.ttf"));
    XPdfFontOptions opt = new XPdfFontOptions(PdfFontEmbedding.Default);

    //I have tried both of these options:
    XFont pdfFont = new XFont(pfc.Families[0], 12, XFontStyle.Regular, opt);
    XFont exoFont = new XFont("Exo", 12);

    gfx.DrawString("Did you receive the product as ordered?", exoFont, XBrushes.Black, 50, 45, XStringFormats.Default);
    gfx.DrawString("Did you receive the product as ordered?", pdfFont, XBrushes.Black, 50, 60, XStringFormats.Default);
```

Answer (score 0):

`pfc.Families[0]` probably does not return the correct string.

`"Exo"` should work provided that "Exo" is the name of the font as displayed in the Fonts applet in the Control Panel of Windows.

Comment: Both of these actually do work, but I cannot get them on the pdf as text.  What I had to do was declare another Graphics object, use the DrawString method to put the text on that with the correct font, then convert the Graphics object to an image and put it on the pdf using DrawImage.  Not too happy about that because the text comes out slightly blurry, but the font won't show up when I use DrawString on the pdf, yet it shows up when I use DrawString on a different Graphics object.

Comment: "convert the Graphics object to an image and put it on the pdf using DrawImage. Not too happy about that because the text comes out slightly blurry." That's odd. Did you try appending text with drawString like this:
PdfDocument inputDocument = PdfReader.Open(file, PdfDocumentOpenMode.Import);
PdfPage page = inputDocument.Pages[0];
page = outputDocument.AddPage(page); 
XGraphics gfx = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(page, XGraphicsPdfPageOptions.Append);
gfx.DrawString(number.ToString(), font, XBrushes.Black, 
    100, 200);
outputDocument.Save("saveFileName.pdf");

Comment: Without the font and without an SSCCE we cannot investigate this matter. See also: http://sscce.org/  You should try `pfc.Add()` instead of `pdf.AddFontFile()`. Syntax is a bit cryptical (probably a Microsoft invention). See also: http://forum.pdfsharp.net/viewtopic.php?p=7591#p7591

Comment: From what I am seeing, neither the PrivateFontCollection object nor the XPrivateFontCollection object has the Add function described in either link.  They are now AddFontFile and AddFont, and none of the overloads for these supports the implementation described.

Comment: The source package of PDFsharp includes the samples. Maybe the samples on the site are outdated, but the sample in the code package will work.